# Wordpress get posts between date range using a date meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have a post type that uses a custom meta field called `start_date`. I want to be able to get all posts that have a `start_date` between date1 and date2. I have been able to figure out how to get posts before or after a date using wp_query by declaring the query type as "DATE".

```
$queryargs = array('meta_key' => 'start_date', 'meta_value' => "2016-06-01", 'meta_compare' => '>', 'type' => 'DATE','posts_per_page' => $instance['pastlimit']);
```

This pulls posts with a start_date after the 1st, but i also want to make it limit dates that dont occur after the 1st of the next month. I cant add the same args again as they dont specify the difference in the constraint. Is it possible to alter the query i have to get posts between a date range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and compare `BETWEEN` an array of `DATE`s:

```
$queryargs = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date', 
            'value' => array('2016-06-01', '2016-07-01'),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN', 
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => $instance['pastlimit']
);
```