# Wordpress meta_query search if month is between two dates

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type called "custom_events" and i would like to filter those events by month.

I have a month filter (dropdown list) that on submit should **show events that start or are already happening in the selected month**. *(Look at the example below)*

**Example:**
We have 3 events

- Event 1: from Jan 10 2018 - Oct 20 2018
- Event 2: from Feb 10 2018 - Mar 20 2018
- Event 3: from Apr 10 2018 - Dec 20 2018

So if i select April from my dropdown list i should get **Event 1**, and **Event 3**. At the moment i only get **Event 3** as a result.

**My current WP_Query args:**

```
$queryArgs = array(
    'post_type'     => 'custom_events',
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
        'key'       => '_startDate',
        'value'     =>  array(20180401, 20180430),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'      => 'DATE'
    )
);
```

So what im trying to get is all events that start from the selected date or their duration is throughout that date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress get posts between date range using a date meta field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081750/wordpress-get-posts-between-date-range-using-a-date-meta-field)

Comment: Let me give you another example:  

We select May from the dropdown and trigger the filter. 
We should get results from events that **start** on may or their duration is **throughout** may...so from the example events below we should get both event 1 and event 2  

**Example events:**
Event 1: starts May 10 and ends May 20; 
Event 2: starts Jan 12 and ends Oct 20   

So no..it's not a duplicate from the question you linked. @cabrerahector